# Create a Firebase using the REST API

Tags: rest, firebase

Is it possible to create new email/password users in Firebase using the REST API?

Comment: Not according to the [API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) or [the guide on authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html). If you are trying to create users via a backend service, you probably just want to [generate your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html).

Comment: Yeah, I am creating my own tokens, but I was hoping to be able to add the registered users as you can through the Firebase dashboard. Doesn't appear to be a way.

Comment: The user creds shown in the account dashboard are only for email/password. They are simply creds for creating tokens and not of any use to you. Store any data in Firebase that you want to retrieve about registered users and you'll be set.

Comment: @Kato that isn't true at all if you're migrating thousands of users (say from a mailing list) and want to bulk-create accounts. In this case, creating user creds become highly relevant and is a valid usecase.

Comment: If you are creating your own tokens, the email/password credentials aren't of any use (you aren't using Firebase Auth, you're creating your own). For a user migration into Firebase's email/password provider method, use an existing SDK (Java, iOS, Node) instead of REST to create the accounts.

Comment: @Kato - any client-side library that provides the ability to create email/password accounts *must* use some REST endpoint to do so, correct? If so, why is this not exposed? If not, how is this accomplished in the client-side libraries?

Comment: Using our Java, JavaScript, Node, Obj-C, or Swift SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with Firebase myself. However, couldn't you just use the JavaScrip API to create a new user (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html)? If you fire this each time a user logs into your application, you will migrate your users over and also have the advantage that users won't need to change their password.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating users from the server:

You can use the official JavaScript library in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), which will let you create users on the server (in JavaScript at least).

Try:

```
➤ npm install firebase
```

And then use it as you would in the browser according to the [official documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html). The following straight from the docs:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.createUser({
  email: "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password: "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
        console.log("The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use.");
        break;
      case "INVALID_EMAIL":
        console.log("The specified email is not a valid email.");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
  }
});
```

Comment: `Firebase` is not a constructor in Firebase v3, also you may not be able to do this at all in v3+